Which API do I use for CRUD on an on-premise sharepoint site?
I have an on-premise Sharepoint server. I want to create an ASP.NET web application that can interact with this server and manipulate items on a particular list, ideally while using Windows authentication for sign-in.
It's not clear to me which API I should be using for SharePoint Server. All I know so far is that my previous attempt to use the PnP framework API isn't going to work, as that only works with SharePoint Online.

It looks like the CSOM API for Sharepoint 2019 works just fine for my purposes.
